# Roll up of Status on Impala SQL

Tags: sql, impala

I have a table with below structured and i need to roll the  results for each system.

```
system      st_cd       tblnm
PDM_TEST    FINAL       CLAIM   
PDM_TEST    EXPIRED     CLAIM   
PDM_TEST    COLD        CLAIM
PDM_TEST    WARM        CLAIM   
PDM_TEST    HOT         CLAIM       
ADM_TEST    COLD        CLAIM   
ADM_TEST    WARM        CLAIM   
ADM_TEST    HOT         CLAIM   
JDM_TEST    HOT         CLAIM
PDM_TEST    HOT         PROVDR  
PDM_TEST    WARM        PROVDR
ADM_TEST    EXPIRED     PROVDR  
ADM_TEST    COLD        PROVDR  
ADM_TEST    WARM        PROVDR  
ADM_TEST    HOT         PROVDR
JDM_TEST    WARM        PROVDR  
JDM_TEST    HOT         PROVDR
```

If systems has only hot,warm,cold st_cd across the tables then system is compliant. If the system has expired or final then its non-compliant.
The output expected is as below after the roll up. How can i achive this in impala sql ?

```
PDM_TEST    NON-COMPLIANT  
ADM_TEST    NON-COMPLIANT           
JDM_TEST    COMPLIANT
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select system,
       (case when sum(case when st_cd not in ('HOT', 'WARM', 'COLD') then 1 else 0 end) > 0
             then 'NON-COMPLIANT'
             else 'COMPLIANT'
        end) as status
from t
group by system;
```

Comment: Thank you so much Gordon. Appreciate that help !